# How to handle numbers which can also have no values sometimes with Logstash and Elasticsearch?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to parse with Logstash a Apache-like log file which contains numbers which are sometimes represented as `-` instead of `0`, like the `%b` format string in Apache can be:

- `%b`: Size of response in bytes, excluding HTTP headers. In CLF format, i.e. a '-' rather than a 0 when no bytes are sent.

(from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats)

In Logstash, I've created a pattern as follow: `NIL_NUMBER (%{NUMBER})|(-)` and Logstash successfully parses all my logs.

However, when I want to insert the content of these log files in Elasticsearch, if I inserted a real number first, Elasticsearch deduces this field is a integer-like field and then inserting this `-` value fails with the following message:

```
MapperParsingException[failed to parse [value]];
  nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "-"];
```

(which I can find in Elasticsearch's logs).

It looks like I don't have this error if I convert all my fields to string before feeding them to Elasticsearch, but it's not the ideal solution as I'm loosing the type of the values.

Converting this value to `null` or `0` before inserting would be the best solution I can see for now, but is there any other solution?
In this case, how would you make this conversion in a generic (I have "lot" of fields in this case) and fast way?

Answer (score 0):

The COMMONAPACHELOG pattern shows you how to solve this:

```
(?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)
```

To explain this in more detail as requested:

First, let's give the bytes field in your pattern some context:

```
foo (%{NUMBER})|(-) bar
```

To really see what's going on in [rubular](http://rubular.com/), I'll expand `%{NUMBER}` into the real regxp. so it becomes:

```
foo ((?:(?<![0-9.+-])(?>[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)|(?:\.[0-9]+)))))|(-) bar
```

Now send in some inputs:

```
"foo 123 bar" gives a group for "123".  Looks good!
"foo - bar" gives a group for "-".  It's a waste, but still OK.
```

Except these also match:

```
"foo 123 spam"
"spam - bar"
```

This is because your "|" is ungrouped.

This is what I was attempting to remedy with my pattern.  It looks like I should have written:

```
foo (%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) bar
```

(the initial "?:" was unneeded)

It differs from yours by changing the placement of the parens to make a group out of "NUMBER or -" instead of two groups.

This pattern correctly processes the 4 samples used above.

Comment: Would you care to explain how it is different from the pattern I wrote in the question and how that would help me?